# In-app billing - item unavailable for purchase

Tags: android, in-app-billing

There are other queries on this, but none seem to provide the answer.

I am trying to implement in-app billing. Code in the real app is based on the dungeons code. I have to managed to get it all working fine on the test ids, but cannot get it to work with a real purchase id. I have:

1. Signed the app by exporting from eclipse.
2. Installed this version to the phone.
3. Uploaded same version to google play, saved it, activated it, but left it unpublished.
4. Created a managed in-app billing item.
5. Published that, although I notice that it does say 'item will only take on published state when app is published', no way round that as far as I can see.
6. Checked carefully that product ids match.
7. Added a gmail test account, made sure this is the primary account on the phone.
8. Waited several hours to make sure it gets propagated across all servers.

And all I get is 'item is unavailable for purchase'. It finds the item OK because in the background on the screen under the dialog is all the right info about it.

What is especially annoying is that the exact same billing code when built into a pure test app, does work, and I can purchase a real managed item. So I am sure the logic in the code is working. It just does not work in the real app with the real managed item.

I feel therefore that this must be some sort of fault with what I/Google have done at the developer console end, not in the app code.

Any ideas? I'm at my wits end with the whole in app billing system.

Comment: Google services always lag. Try tomorrow.

Comment: It's had over 24 hours now ....

Comment: This is also covered in:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020587/in-app-billing-item-requested-not-available-for-purchase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just time in the end.Took over two days to sort itself out.