# Android in-app billing getting dialog like “item not found”

Tags: android, android-billing

I am working on in-app billing.
I have done all the steps.
When I run my signed apk, and after clicking on buy button I am getting this dialog "item not found". Also after clicking on ok another dialog will be open like "the item you requested is not available for purchase " 
Whats the problem with my app ?
I am also using another account for test.

Comment: Are you following the nice step-by-step procedure at http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html ?

Comment: it might take several time to effect the products in to your code. i have also same problem but when I check next day with the same code, i was working and I was able to complete the in-app purchase.

Comment: hello Rushbh patel as u told i already w8t for 2 hour.but still not solve my problem..

Comment: Then it may be problem with code or nonce generated data or product id...

Answer (score 1):

Did add the following line to your Proguard configuration file:

-keep class com.android.vending.billing.**

Answer (score 0):

Add inapp products in your developer account for that application, and use the same SKU. It will resolve the issue.

Comment: Add inapp products in your developer account for that application..i am not understand ...can u explain me....