# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.viralandroid.test/com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity}:

Tags: android, android-intent, paypal

How could I solve the problem below? I searched a lot but I didn't figure out.

I am using a fragment instead of an activity to call PaymentActivity.

Thanks in advance.

There is a piece of code below.

```
    public void executarPagtoPayPal()
{
    SearchResultsAdapter searchResultsAdapter = new SearchResultsAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Produto>());

    PayPalPayment coisasAComprar = searchResultsAdapter.prepararCarrinhoFinal();

    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PaymentActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, payPalConfiguration);
    i.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, coisasAComprar);

    startActivityForResult(i,CODIGO_PAGTO);
}
```

> 06-01 13:26:31.841 12770-12770/com.viralandroid.test E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: 
>                                                                  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Invalid name: 
>                                                                      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
>                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2281)
>                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245)
>                                                                      at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.br.createFromParcel(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2252)
>                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152)
>                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
>                                                                      at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
>                                                                      at android.os.BaseBundle.containsKey(BaseBundle.java:269)
>                                                                      at android.content.Intent.hasExtra(Intent.java:5055)
>                                                                      at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.d.b(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
>                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
>   06-01 13:26:31.841 12770-12770/com.viralandroid.test D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   06-01 13:26:31.841 12770-12770/com.viralandroid.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: com.viralandroid.test, PID: 12770
>                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.viralandroid.test/com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2695)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
>                                                                           Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: 
>                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2295)
>                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245)
>                                                                              at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.br.createFromParcel(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2252)
>                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152)
>                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
>                                                                              at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
>                                                                              at android.os.BaseBundle.containsKey(BaseBundle.java:269)
>                                                                              at android.content.Intent.hasExtra(Intent.java:5055)
>                                                                              at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.d.b(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
>                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` where is code ???????

Comment: Hope this will help you [CLICK HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34547902/599841)

Comment: check PaymentActivity is declared in menifest file or not ,if not declare it and check.

Comment: Have you tried to Clean and Rebuild the app?

Comment: Your Paypal sdk did not found. Go to paypal documentation since you will get the right way. got to this link https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/

Comment: Now I put the error completely.

Comment: Naveen I declared PaymentActivity in manifest. What is causing the problem is another thing.

Comment: Abdallah, I did a Clean and Rebuild but the problem still remains.

Comment: Post the code you are using to start the `PaymentActivity`. You are putting some junk in the `Intent` that is causing this error.

Comment: @DavidWasser I put the code.

Comment: It looks like the contents of the `PayPalPayment` that you are putting in the `Intent` are not correct. Please validate that this object has all the correct data.

Comment: You are right @DavidWasser

Comment: I love this website. I love you.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer, maybe it will help someone else with the same problem. Then I can be loved even more ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the contents of the PayPalPayment that you are putting in the Intent are not correct. Please validate that this object has all the correct data.