# Item you requested is not available for purchase - android in app billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

As I am developing an application which uses in app billing, I am not able to test it using my own product ID. I have followed every step as documented on developer site. I have,

1. Uploaded the signed apk with release certificated to developer console.
2. I have published my apk to alpha channel.
3. I have listed my product Ids to developer console.
4. I have activated my product Ids and on developer console it is marked as Active.
5. I have listed the test account in developer console.
6. I have installed the same apk that I uploaded to developer console to my deveice.
7. The device is logged in with the test account not the developer account.
8. The Id that I use in my app is same as I had listed on console as per logcat message.

But, I am getting Item is not available for purchase.

Do not know what's wrong.

I know that this question has been asked on stack overflow before several times, and I have gone through each and every one of them, but none of the solutions seems to work for me so please do not close this issue as duplicate.

Comment: Is the app in published status on alpha channel? I know you've written its published but it takes some time before it actually gets published.

Comment: Yes, my application is published in alpha channel, and It has been a couple of days after publishing it. On Developer console, it clearly says that the app is published.

Comment: I'm having the same problem all of a sudden (it worked well before) with the exact same steps as you. I have a specific test account on google play where I only publish my app in Alpha. Everything seems ok, I can retrieve the sku details of my products but when I want to buy I have the "item not available" error.

Comment: same here guys .. retrieving sky details I get the products but when I want to buy it say:: item not available....

Answer (score 56):

Found the solution for me, I had to add the testers account to alpha also. Google changed its policy, you need to be an alpha tester and not just be added to the test account list.
My steps :

- Go to Alpha APK
- Switch alpha testing type
- Create a list
- Add my tester email
- Save
- Submit update (top right of the page)
- Wait for 15 minutes
- Open opt-in url with test account and click on "Become a tester"

Comment: thaaaaaaank you for the updated list, my problem was in the last point, i have wasted lots of time searching how to solve the above error, the opt-in url is MANDATORY for IAB to work

Comment: Yes, I also figured this out, that you also need to add test account e-mail to alpha testing group also, after doing this it solved the problem.

Comment: +1 for the last point - I was already part of a Google Group for alpha testing and I thought that was enough - you still need to select "Become a tester" though

Comment: After making a list and adding your e-mail, make sure to **check the box under the ACTIVE column**. +1

Comment: See my response on another question with a bunch of stuff to check if you're facing the same issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35132936/2064171

Comment: This did it for me - I had not done the very last step to "become a tester."

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 8):

## Just add your e-mail address to `Lisense Testing`

0) Go to Google Play Console

1) Go to Settings (in left drawer)

[image]

2) Go to `Developer Account` (and `Account Details`)

3) Go to section `License Testing` (at the bottom)

4) Add `Gmail accounts with testing access`

5) Save changes

[image]

Do not need any `alpha release` or anything else.

Comment: Do you need gmail accounts for license testing? Is it possible to add any other account?

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting this error. For this 1st generate a new signed app with upgraded version and then follow these steps

- open google play console
- Go to Release Management->App Release
- In beta track create a app http://prntscr.com/ntxgr5

If app is create on beta track then go to production but if u click on go to production, then u getting some error like draft is full for that u have to clear the draft

- In app release top most track is production track click on edit release
  in left of bottom a Discard button is present click on that and remove that app

After that go to beta track and go to production and conform it
after 15-20 minute your latest app will reflect on play-store

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to add the e-mail (Gmail) logged in my fone.

Comment: thats a different error message will be returned in this case