# Test Google In App Purchase paying real money

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, developer-console

So, I have implemented IAP(in app purchase) in my application and successfully tested it with real product ids. My app is published to Alpha and everything worked fine (payments were not real of course).

I have then closed my Alpha testing. Now, instead of making either real or testing methods, I only see an error message: `The item you requested is not available for purchase.`.

When the app will start to make real payments instead of testing? What do I need to do for that? Do I need to publish it to the production for that to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do real purchase even if your app is in Alpha testing.
The real purchases will be reflected in Google merchant page with an Order Id.

App does not have any knowledge of purchase type, if it a real or test. Play Store is the master which knows all the deatils of a purchase.

For a test purchase you will be adding you test mail with test access in *LICENSE TESTING*.

To make a real purchase with the account, remove that account from the list showing *Gmail accounts with testing access* in developer console. Thus you can make real purchases.

Over All,

If your account is in *Settings->Account Details->LICENSE TESTING* group, the purchases will be test purchases else it is a Real Purchase.

Comment: Whenever I remove my account from Settings/License testing list, I get the error: "The item you requested is not available for purchase". Again, test purchases work fine. Also, what should I do with closed Beta testing settings? Do I have to remove my account from there too? Or should I disable Beta testing completely in order to see real purchases?

Comment: Thank you, waiting a little solved the problem. Accepted!

Comment: If you want to purchase an item in Alpha/Beta You account must become a tester of that app. Please follow up this links, may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582386/android-inapp-billing-the-item-you-requested-is-not-available-for-purchase-inc

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391047/item-you-requested-is-not-available-for-purchase-android-in-app-billing

Comment: thanks, the question was about how to disable testing :)