# Firebase: The item you requested is not available for purchase

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-console

So I know this question has been asked quite a few times, however they are all based on a beta deploy from Google Play Console. In my case I have done a beta deploy through Firebase. I'm not able to find anything in regards to Firebase but tonnes on Google Play Console.

From what I've seen:

1. [GooglePlay: The item you requested is not available for purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35833930/googleplay-the-item-you-requested-is-not-available-for-purchase)
2. [Android InApp Billing: The item you requested is not available for purchase. Inconsistent on a different google accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582386/android-inapp-billing-the-item-you-requested-is-not-available-for-purchase-inc)
3. [Item you requested is not available for purchase - android in app billing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391047/item-you-requested-is-not-available-for-purchase-android-in-app-billing)

Is it right that you have to have your app deployed through the Google Play Console in order to make in app purchases? I'm just trying to do a beta test for in app purchases but I get:

> Error: The item you requested is not available for purchase

If it can be done on Firebase, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Thought I should mention that it was my mistake. I tried to deploy a test release with `fastlane` and in my `Fastfile` for the beta lane I did not add the properties for apk signing. If you are using fastlane to distribute a beta test make sure to have something similar to below in your Fastfile for the lane that you are calling otherwise in app billing won't work:

```
lane :beta do
  # ...
  gradle(
    task: 'assemble',
    build_type: 'Release'
    properties: {
        "android.injected.signing.store.file" => "[key_keystore]",
        "android.injected.signing.store.password" => "[store_password]",
        "android.injected.signing.key.alias" => "[key_alias]",
        "android.injected.signing.key.password" => "[key_password]",
      }
  )

  firebase_app_distribution(
    app: "your_app_id",
    groups: "your_test_group"
  )
  # ...
end
```

Note you can find the credential properties in your project's `bundle.gradle` file.