# In app purchase not working: item not available for purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Using in app purchase in my application. I have double checked the products are listed at playstore and in active states. plus the application is published but in beta testing. product ids using in my code is very same as in playstore. I'm testing the signed apk on phone.

Problem: whenever i click the button and try to get product it endup like this.
[image]

please help. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step you need to follow, once launches an inapp products in your application.

- You have latest In-app Billing Version configured in application
- Apk is in published state but in beta testing or any other testing
- List the products with unique ids at play store panel
- Change the state of products to active state
- Product ids are same in source code as well in play store (double check)
- You have signed apk installed in phone
- versionCode of published apk & testing apk must be same
- you have added a tester at play store under same apk
- You need to test inapp from very same email, you have added at google play store (as tester)

once i followed all steps this error is gone. In my case it is because of tester's email :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a different (test) account than the one you're signed in to the developer console with, and add it in the developer console.

Edit: see here: [the item you requested is not available for purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117081/the-item-you-requested-is-not-available-for-purchase)

Comment: i have tested apk on different phones. within those phone there is not same test account login. yes have seen this post before. problem still stands

Answer (score 0):

I think, you might miss something but to get the missing part, you must share your code of InApp Billing section. By the way, you can also use the library project from https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3.

Comment: em even getting the same error, when running this sample. don't know what wrong. should i change email from where em logged in playstore on mobile?

Comment: I think, you should try that. By the way, are you using your test account as primary account on your device?

Comment: yes. the same account. listed in closed beta testing

Comment: Did you try to set product to inactive and active again? Also you should try to setup a different product and see if this works.

Comment: even i added new products with different ids. error is same

Comment: Are you sure that the product is ACTIVE?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a caching problem with Google Play services. Clear out the cache and try again.