# Android InApp Billing: The item you requested is not available for purchase. Inconsistent on a different google accounts

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-billing

Please do not close this as duplicate without reading everything.

**Case Summary:** 
Two google test accounts were used for IAP transactions using the same app build. One works, one doesn't. Both google accounts have working credit cards and can buy IAP from other apps.

**More Details:**
We have a new Unity-Android build released to our testers and we have 2 different google accounts for IAP testing. Surprisingly, one account can do test purchases successfully without a glitch, while the other one always gets: *"The item you requested is not available for purchase."*

The non-working account had been used for testing IAP in the past and we didn't have a problem. There was no changes in the google groups, the account is still a member of our test group for this app.

Does anyone have a clue why is it not working in one google account, while in another, it's fine?

Note:

1. Same build was used.
2. Both accounts worked successfully with IAP with older versions.
3. Both accounts are still member of the app's test group.
4. The non-working account was recently used to make a purchase in another game and it worked just fine.

What are we missing?

Comment: See my response on another question with a bunch of stuff to check if you're facing the same issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35132936/2064171

Answer (score 23):

I sent a ticket to Google Support and they finally replied:

> We recently updated in-app product testing requirements. Each tester
>   needs to opt-in to your alpha or beta test before they can test in-app
>   products. If they are not opted-in they will see an error that the
>   in-app item is not available for purchase.

From: [http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html:](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html)

> Important: To test in-app products or make in-app purchases in your
>   alpha or beta channel app, **each tester needs to opt-in to your app’s
>   alpha or beta test**. On your test’s opt-in URL, your testers will get
>   an explanation of what it means to be a tester and a link to opt-in.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! In my case, IAPs took more than an hour to enable after first time publishing.

Comment: @Qorbani, every update you make in the dashboard does take a couple of hours to take effect. I believe it always show that message on top after you publish changes. :) I usually check the next morning to save myself unnecessary headaches. :D