# error in app purchase android 'item you requested is not available for purchase

Tags: android

For IAP after clicking on a button I can see 'the item is not available for purchase
I have full rollout apk in alpha test
and added test user
and also verify sky
I can't see any price and buy option, I have tried following code

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
                IInAppBillingService mService;
                TextView textView;
                IabHelper mHelper;
                Bundle skuDetails;
               private BillingClient mbilBillingClient;

                public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1001;
                String sku = "mycodes";

                ServiceConnection mServiceConn;
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);
                    String base64EncodedPublicKey="mylicencekey";

                    // compute your public key and store it in base64EncodedPublicKey
                    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
                    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                                // Oh no, there was a problem.
                                Log.d("tags", "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
                            }
                            // Hooray, IAB is fully set up!
                        }
                    });
                    mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
                        @Override
                        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                            mService = null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name,
                                                       IBinder service) {
                            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);

                        }
                    };

                    Intent serviceIntent =
                            new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
                    serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
                    bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

                    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            try {
                                Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(),"ravin", "inapp",null);
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
                                startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
                                        REQUEST_CODE, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
                                        Integer.valueOf(0));
                            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
                @Override
                protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "hi="+resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
                        int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
                        String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
                        String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");

                        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                                String sku = jo.getString("productId");
                                Log.e("error","You have bought the " + sku + ". Excellent choice,adventurer!");
                            }
                            catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e("error","Failed to parse purchase data.");
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onDestroy() {
                    super.onDestroy();
                    if (mService != null) {
                        unbindService(mServiceConn);
                    }
                }
```

Please anyone can give a solution, I have also added BILLING Permission and use same sign apk and version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18172192/2941375

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error only if you forget to add your product in your play store account(In-app products). Once you added the product, then replace the `sku` with `new product id`. you can use this(random working sku) `androidtestpayment` for testing.